# Lua syntax error in newImage code

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am new to Lua programming and was designing a game in Corona SDK. Whenever I enter the following code and run it it says `syntax error '=' expected near 'newImage'`. So any help would be appreciated!

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

  local centerX = display.contentCenterX
  local centerY = display.contentCenterY


-- create playscreen

 display.newImage("background.png")
```

Comment: Weird man, I tried this same code and its worked fine for me. What's your Corona version and text editor?

Comment: @MaiconFeldhaus Dude found the error.I did not save it before launching it

Comment: Taaha you are a legend!